# Making a tabbed cef sharp browser rename tab page

Tags: c#, cefsharp

i have been creating a cefsharp browser in C#. i have made it so you can have multiple tabs and it loads the pages correctly. however, i cannot seem to find how i can rename the tab to the name of the page.

this is the code in the load event for form1.cs:

```
                    Cef.Initialize();
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "Settings");
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        Tab newtab = new Tab();
        newtab.Show();
        newtab.TopLevel = false;
        newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tab.Controls.Add(newtab);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
```

i have tried:

```
                    private void myBrowser_isLoading(object sender) 
    {
        myBrowser.Parent.Parent.Text = myBrowser.Title;
    }
```

but that doesn't work.

then this is the code for tab.cs:

```
                    public Tab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Start the browser after initialize global component
        InitializeChromium();

    }
    public CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser myBrowser;
    public bool nav = new bool();
    public void InitializeChromium()
    {


         myBrowser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com");
        this.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
        myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        myBrowser.Parent = panel2;
    if (nav == true)
        {
            myBrowser.Load(textBox1.Text);
            nav = false;
        }



    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();

    }
```

again, i am using c# with the latest build of cef sharp(or atleast the one installed from the nuget package manager).

Comment: i forgot to mention i am using a windows forms project (you can probably already tell).

Comment: also it is parent.parent.text because the browser's parent is a panel.

Comment: The `CefSharp` source contains a `WinForms` example that's tabbed, check it out for a reference. Subscribe to the `TitleChanged` event for notifications when the title changed.

Comment: @amaitland hey, thanks for your help, but i have been looking all through the cef sharp source and couldnt find where the TitleChanged event was. if you could go more indepth or even take the time to answer the question, that would be great :)

Comment: I don't have a clue what's going on with your code. Just search the solution for the keyword.

Comment: @amaitland i have already done that, thanks for the help.

Comment: really though, i really need an answer

Comment: The best I have time for is pointers. The `CefSharp` source contains a working tabbed browser, what more do you need?

Comment: @amaitland i have already looked all through the cef sharp winforms source, i found nothing to help (although i did find stuff to help for other things), im not saying you have to answer, i just need an answer from anyone who knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tab function in form1.cs, you need to add a title changed function like this

```
browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
```

you also need to specify what browser is and set dockstyle to fill like this

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("google.com");
tab.Controls.Add(browser);
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

now for the OnBrowserTitleChanged, you will need an EventArg which will tell the tab to have the document title in this format

```
this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => browserTabControl.SelectedTab.Text = args.Title);
```

this will add the document title to the tabcontrol browserTabControl is the name of the tabcontrol you will have to change browserTabControl to whatever name you have for the tabcontrol. Also the code you have does not belong with cef initialize. you need to create an addNewTab method with all the functions that will be processed when you want to add a new tab. Also, you cannot use a panel if you want to have tabs. you need a tabcontrol

Comment: First of all, im not using a panel to do it. i made the panel its parent, then the panel is the child of the tab control. i also have an addnewtab method. also, i have already found out about the cef.initialize thing and fixed it.

Comment: also, it gives me an error under this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(()  saying... wait first i need to say something that just MIGHT change things. i have it in a form  called "tab" every time you create a tab, it does this:                                                                                          TabPage tab = new TabPage();
            Tab newtab = new Tab();
            newtab.Show();
            newtab.TopLevel = false;
            newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tab.Controls.Add(newtab);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);

Comment: @JamDoggie anyway, it says its not referenced in the class. that might be stupid of me.

Comment: If you use a tabcontrol, you dont need to use a panel reread the code i provided you should have no problem understanding it and you also need to look at the documents on github to complete the addNewTab method. If you still have problems with this, you should try to do something else

Comment: i used a panel to minipulate the browser control easy without having to do it in code. i have since figured this out, i will mark the answer you gave as correct because the error was on my part. thanks.